# Any hooks for HttpClient?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

When making a REST call, the usual approach with C# is:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.SendAsync(....);
}
```

But what if I want every single outbound request to have a custom header, without manual coding?  With a WCF proxy I can achieve that result by adding a global endpoint behavior (e.g. IMessageInspector) which will hook every outbound call.

With HttpClient, I don't think such a hook point exists.  Perhaps the best I can do is to create an extension method for HttpClient which automatically adds the header.  Unfortunately, that means that every developer must still voluntarily comply and remember to manually invoke the extension method.

Any solution I'm overlooking?

p.s. I understand that REST is supposed to be light-weight, and so much of the abstraction of WCF is jettisoned.  Still, no harm in asking...

Comment: When I do this, I make a function that returns an `HttpClient` object already set up with the headers I need.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom `HttpMessageHandler`:

```
public class YourServiceMessageHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Add header to request here

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And pass it to the `HttpClient` constructor:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new YourServiceMessageHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

No hooks like that, but if you are writing a HTTP API, you can just hide the entire uploading process in your class so the users of your API only call something like `SendData(dataPackage);`, and instead of using HttpRequest in your extension as a parent, you just create an instance of it so others don't see what you are doing.